# Windows Azure Cache with a multi tenant application

Tags: azure

I have in development a multi tenant application that I am deploying to azure.

I would like to take advantage of the windows azure cache service as it looks like it will be a great performance improvement vs hitting the database for each call.

Lets say I have 2 tables . Businesses and Customers. A business can have multiple customers and the business table contains details about the business.

Business details don't change often but customer information is changing constantly for each of the different tenants.

I assume I need 2 named instances (1 for business details and 1 for customers)

Is 2 named caches enough or do I need separate these for each of the tenants? I think 2 would be ok as if I have to create separate for each it will get expensive pretty quickly.

Thank you.

Comment: I would be caching the business details but not the customers. But you could used just 1 cache for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different named caches is interesting if you have different cache requirements (Expiry policy, default TTL, Notifications, High Availability, ...).

In you case you could simply look at using different **[Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn386102.aspx)** per tenant:

*Windows Azure Cache supports the creation and use of user-defined regions. A region is a subgroup for cached items. Regions also support the annotation of cached items with additional descriptive strings called tags. Regions support the ability to perform search operations on any tagged items in that region.*

This would allow you to split your named cache (you would only need one), in regions per tenant holding the businesses and customers for that tenant. And if the businesses don't change that often, you can simple change the TTL for those items to 1, 2, .. hours.